# Setpoint velocity change isn't taken over by axis

Tags: plc, twincat

I use function from MC_Jog to do the movement. However, when I change the Jog's velocity to 900, the Setpoint velocity still shows 100.

Why is Setpoint velocity displaying 100 instead of 900?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the mode parameter. It's set to `MC_JOGMODE_STANDARD_SLOW` by default, meaning "low velocity for manual functions" specified in the TwinCAT System Manager will be used.  You can change it to `MC_JOGMODE_CONTINOUS` to use Velocity input.

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_mc2/70120459.html?id=7121036612998147748